# Get the value of a cell referenced with full address

Tags: office-js

I have an Excel AddIn and I have a taskpane with a textbox.
I would like to fill this textbox with a cell address, i.e. =Sheet1!A1 or =Sample!B4 ...., and get the value of this cell.
I fill my textbox with a cell address and I want to solve this address with the value of the reference cell.
I'm using javascript without jquery.
How can I do this with from my addind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your scenario, I think you just need to read the address from the textbox. Parse it with JavaScript string `split()` method to separate the worksheet name from the grid address. Then pass the worksheet name to [Workbook.worksheets.getItem()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#getitem-key-) to get a reference to the worksheet. Then pass the grid address to the [worksheet.getRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#getrange-address-) method. Then use [Range.load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#load-option-) to load the `values` property and then `context.sync`. This will bring the value of the range into your add-in.

Comment: More or lees, but my problem is to solve a cell address in the described format to get the value